# How to call function in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to call `SaveFile` function from `SaveNRunXUtility` which is in the same class. So, there is how I do it:

```
 def SaveFile(self):
    try:
        ...
        self.currentFile=tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', efaultextension='.txt')
        if self.currentFile is None:
          return
        ...
        print 'here'
        ...
    except:
        tkMessageBox.showerror(...)

def SaveNRunXUtility(self):
    try:
        self.SaveFile
        ...
    except:
        tkMessageBox.showerror(...)
```

I can't see `here` in my terminal, also there is no save file dialog, and no exceptions. So, how should I call `SaveFile`?

Comment: Why are you using 3-4 Tab spaces for indentation , single tab also works for most of people I guess ? and code looks cleaner as well

Comment: "I'm trying to call `SaveFile` function" - so what prevents you from doing so instead of mentioning the function's name? (SCNR)

Answer (score 4):

```
self.SaveFile()
```

You need to invoke the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try `self.SaveFile()` instead of `self.SaveFile`.